# Clear text of MultiAutoCompleteTextView after click of hint item

Tags: java, android, multiautocompletetextview

I am utilizing Multiautocompletetextview in my application. I have succesfully implemented the functionality however the issue is that whenever I click on the suggested item that I am choosing and return to the edit text to add another value to the list, the same text that is part of my past search still remains.

I would like for the text to be cleared after clicking on a given suggestion so that from there I dont have to manually delete the remenants of my past entry.

As the site android documentation describes my solution looks like so

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), simple_dropdown_item_1line, allGroups);
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView multiAutoCompleteTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView);
    multiAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    multiAutoCompleteTextView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

Not sure where to look into clicklistener as ive looked in the adapter and tokenizer to set to clear the text after click.

Appreciate the time and direction.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try the Code Below on your ClickListener,

```
Your_AutoCompleteText.setText("");
```

Comment: I actually know that that would achieve the task I am actually looking for the listener based on the code above that I used. I searched the adapter and tokenizer neither have the word click in it.

Comment: well, Have you tried, multiAutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener ???  Is this TextView even CLickable??